# Jupyter notebook shows a blank homepage on browser

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

[image]

When I open the Jupyter notebook, it shows this blank page on the browser. Everything was work fine, but suddenly the homepage become completely blank.

[image]

This the terminal windows. I followed the instruction that are here in the terminal window, but still it shows a blank white page on browser.

Comment: Try removing the `/tree` from the end of the URL.

Comment: Try running jupyter notebook in a non-user folder. For example, documents. Windows may be blocking access to the /user/ directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your current working directory is empty, just navigate to the root of your drive like `E:` for E drive then enter `jupyter notebook` command.